# How to fix regex to strip <blockquote></blockquote> tags with \n inside?

Tags: java, android, regex

I am a java regex newbie so I am asking here if you could help me solve the problem. So I have a string of words that have blockquote tags such as below:

```
<blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum neque nisi, accumsan id lacus vitae, eleifend hendrerit dui. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum quis tincidunt neque. Etiam dignissim molestie lorem non commodo.\n</blockquote>\nDuis porta consectetur turpis, rutrum pellentesque nibh porttitor quis. Suspendisse porta mollis ullamcorper. Vivamus aliquam, diam id molestie eleifend, ipsum quam interdum tortor, placerat feugiat urna elit vel metus. Phasellus aliquet metus tincidunt leo tempus, sit amet hendrerit mi malesuada. Aenean maximus a purus quis auctor. Vivamus risus metus, rhoncus ut accumsan id, efficitur sit amet nunc. Sed quis urna a ante ornare laoreet. Nullam auctor gravida mauris ut aliquam.\n\n<blockquote>Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum quis tincidunt neque. Etiam dignissim molestie lorem non commodo. Nam id cursus eros. Sed tempus tempor nulla id venenatis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In in varius massa\n</blockquote>Cras congue metus nulla, a laoreet lorem bibendum dictum. Aenean nec velit porta purus ornare dictum sed dictum massa. Suspendisse imperdiet neque nec lorem commodo, ut congue nisl placerat. Maecenas nec justo feugiat, faucibus turpis at, tincidunt dui. Fusce tincidunt suscipit lectus nec dictum.\n
```

I need to remove blockquote tags and strip the content inside and also remove \n inside blockquoutes. I need to display this in a textview. So far this is what I've done:

```
public static String replaceAllBlockQuoteTags(String postText) {
    return postText.replaceAll("<\\/?\\s*" + BLOCKQUOTE_TAG + ".*?>", "").replaceAll("<\\/?\\n*\" + BLOCKQUOTE_TAG + \"");
}
```

But it's not removing the \n. Any ideas how to solve this problem? I'd appreciate your response. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below function, It will remove both blockquotes and new line characters

```java
public static String replaceAllBlockQuoteTags(String postText) {
        return postText.replace("\n</blockquote>", "").replace("<blockquote>", "");
}
```

Comment: Instead it's wrapping the next paragraph that doesn't have the blockquote tags

Comment: I updated the answer, can you check wether it works now

Comment: Almost works but it doesn't get the correct result.